# SQL Server and Chinese character on INSERT/SELECT query

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I use SQL Server 2014 with collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

I have a C# program that inserts Chinese character into my database, for example :

```
"你","好".
```

In SQL Server Management Studio, I can see it clearly and I can also search on it through N"你".

The issue is that for some character, it didn't work :

```
"〇", "㐄".
```

When my C# program start to insert this two characters, I have a CONSTRAINT UNIQUE exception raised (because I put it into my database a unique constraint for Chinese character).

> InnerException = {"Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'AK_Dictionary_Chinese'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Dictionary'. The duplicate key value is (㐄).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."

And here is my issue : it seems that these two Chinese character (and I have around 70 similar issue) are not well converted into UTF8 and I encounter issue. If I remove the unique constraint, then of course I can insert it into my database and can see it through SQL Server Management Studio. But when I search for the character using N"〇", the database answer me multiple matches : "〇", "㐄"...

So how can I deal with that ? I tried to change the collation for the Chinese one but I have the same issue...

Thanks for your help.

HOW can I add the Chinese characters in my c# program?

My entity object :

```
public partial class Dictionary
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Chinese { get; set; }
    public string Pinyin { get; set; }
    public string English { get; set; }
}
```

I just add a new entity object to my database and call SaveChanges();

```
var word1 = new Dictionary()
{
   Chinese = "〇",
   Pinyin = "a",
   English = "b",
};

var word2 = new Dictionary()
{
   Chinese = "㐄",
   Pinyin = "c",
   English = "bdsqd",
};

 // We insert it into our Db
 using (var ctx = new DBEntities())
 {
   ctx.Dictionaries.Add(word1);
   ctx.Dictionaries.Add(word2);
   ctx.SaveChanges();
 }
```

If you want to try at home, here is a small sql script that reproduce the issue. You can execute it through SQL MANAGEMENT STUDIO :

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Value  NVARCHAR(256)
);  

INSERT INTO @T(Value) VALUES (N'〇'), (N'㐄');

SELECT * FROM @T;


SELECT * FROM @T WHERE Value = N'〇';
```

Comment: How are you inserting them from your C# program?

Comment: I think you need to pick a different collation for this. One specifically oriented towards the language rules you want to make use of.

Comment: Characters in SQL Server are **never** converted to UTF-8, since SQL Server does not support UTF-8 - it uses UCS-2 (UTF-16) exclusively

Comment: @marc_s : so if sql server use UTF-16, it should be capable to store the Chinese character ? Why I have this issue ? Damien: I try twice with the default chinese collation : Chinese_PRC_CI_AS but same issue

Comment: First thing I have difficult seeing - are the characters stored correctly in the tables? Are they NVARCHAR and can you verify the data if you open it via management studio?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen if I add the unique constraint, not working because I can't add the character (CONSTRAINT UNIQUE). If I remove the constraint, yes I can insert and see the different character in management studio (display is ok). But the issue is that it seems that even if the display is different, if I execute a SELECT query on it (no matter through management studio or C# LINQ), it will just match both character like if they are "equal".

Comment: *If* the data is inserted correctly - I'd try to change collation as @Damien_The_Unbeliever suggested to something better suited for Chinese language rules. A quick way to test collations / data duplication is to select and group by.

Comment: Thanks @AllanS.Hansen I just query it on all possible collation and found the one that match. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. In fact, the Chinese character is "traditional" and SQL SERVER need a bit of help. Collation was the right idea, but I had to specify Chinese traditional for that (to find it I just query the sample provided with all possible collation....).

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Value  NVARCHAR(256)
) ;  

INSERT INTO @T(Value) VALUES (N'〇'), (N'㐄');

SELECT * FROM @T;

SELECT * FROM @T WHERE Value = N'㐄' COLLATE Chinese_Traditional_Pinyin_100_CI_AS;
```

Sorry for making lose your time, I really tried with Chinese collation but not the traditional one (I didn't know that it was traditional character...).

Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this without specifying Collation every time!

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Value  NVARCHAR(256)
) ;  

INSERT INTO @T(Value) VALUES (N'〇'), (N'㐄'), (N'㐄〇'), (N'〇㐄');

SELECT * FROM @T;

SELECT * FROM @T  WHERE CAST(Value AS varbinary) like CAST(N'〇%' AS varbinary)
SELECT * FROM @T  WHERE CAST(Value AS varbinary) like CAST(N'㐄%' AS varbinary)
```

Comment: This is also available, but I assume that for performance reason (it's in fact a dictionary, so with lot of data) is better to specify the collation for the specific column. But your method works too :-)